# Change transparency of one segment in a stacked area plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

Say I have some timeseries data to display, and I want the viewer to take away two things: a guaranteed value (y1) and an upper limit (y2).

I want to display this through a stacked area plot (using matplotlib, or in the example below, through the pandas wrapper).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- Define df ---
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':range(1,6),
    'y1':[1,4,6,8,9],
    'y2':[2,2,7,10,12]})

# --- Set xaxis as index ---
df.set_index('x', inplace=True)

# --- Plot using pandas ---
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.area(ax=ax)
```

[image: baseline]

To show that y2 is an upper limit, I want to reduce the transparency (alpha) of y2 without touching the alpha of y1. Because the `alpha` parameter doesn't take a list (i.e. `[1, 0.5]`), I would typically do this by accessing the lines directly.

```
for line in fig.gca().lines:
   line.set_alpha(0.1)
```

However this isn't changing anything. I've also tried this using `plt.stackplot()` to no result either.

How do I access the transparency of a single y value set within a stacked area plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to get the RGBA form of the second color in the default matplotlib color cycle (orange), and pass that to `df.plot`. Runnable code with modifications:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba

# --- Define df ---
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':range(1,6),
    'y1':[1,4,6,8,9],
    'y2':[2,2,7,10,12]})

# --- Set xaxis as index ---
df.set_index('x', inplace=True)

# --- Get default orange, make it translucent  ---
default_colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
# to_rgba returns a tuple; python tuples are immutable. 
# Convert to list in order to modify the last element (alpha channel)
new_orange = list(to_rgba(default_colors[1]))
# Change alpha channel from 1 to 0.2
new_orange[-1] = 0.2

# --- Plot using pandas ---
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.area(ax=ax, color=['C0', new_orange])
```

#### Original Answer Below

This is a fragile solution that will work only on your specific plot order: get a list of child elements of the axis, then change the alpha value of the second child (the orange polygon) and the fourth child (the orange line). Run this after your existing code:

```
# --- Reduce alpha of orange polygon and line ---
children = ax.get_children()    
children[1].set_alpha(0.2)
children[3].set_alpha(0.2)
```

[image: Modified plot]

Comment: Thanks Peter. This is a good solution, my problem was in looking for the lines instead of the children.

Comment: @skoeb that's great to hear! I just realized that another solution would be to pass an RGBA color to plot: `df.plot.area(ax=ax, color=['C0', (1.0, 0.498, 0.055, 0.2)])`. To get the RGBA values of the second color (orange) in the default color cycle, use `from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba; to_rgba(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'][1])`. I'll edit this into the answer for completeness.

Comment: Although it's not in the example I provided, I usually like plotting with a seaborn grid in the background, which requires transparency for the full effect. Thanks!